# npm run webpack -- -w not watching

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

If I install webpack globally, then I can run

```
webpack -w
```

and it works fine, and continues running, watching my files. If I try to run it locally with

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "webpack": "webpack"
}
```

cmd

```
npm run webpack -- -w
```

Then it runs, but it does not watch the files. It completes and return to input on cmd in windows.

**Edit:**

If I put the `-w` directly in my `package.json` then it will watch correctly, but I want the watch to be optional

```
"scripts": {
    "webpack": "webpack -w"
}
```

Comment: I don't think it works that way. That said, you can still install and run webpack globally: this will not alter your scripts at all, and you'll be still able to watch the files!

Answer (score 0):

You could add another entry to scripts in package.json, something like:

```
"scripts": {
    "webpack": "webpack",
    "webpack:w": "webpack -w",
}
```

And then run `npm run webpack` or `npm run webpack:w` depending on which one you want.

Obs: it doesnt have to be ":w" (or even start with "webpack") but anything you want (it could be "theonewithwatch" =D -- and you'd use `npm run theonewithwatch`), just to differenciate it from the one without the watch.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `npm run webpack -- -w` you will see that it actually executes:

```
webpack "-w"
```

Apparently, webpack does not properly recognize that arguments when quoted.

But actually, you don't even need a `webpack` script. You can just use [npx](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/162869356040/introducing-npx-an-npm-package-runner):

```
npx webpack
npx webpack -w
```